# NSURLSession - How to support http authentication challenge

Tags: ios, http, authentication, swift2, nsurlsession

below `NSURLSession`delegate function supporting only **https** receive challenge.

```
func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, didReceiveChallenge challenge: NSURLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: (NSURLSessionAuthChallengeDisposition, NSURLCredential?) -> Void)
```

In `Info.plist` , I included below stuff to allow all connections:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

to support http as well but the `NSURLSession` Delegate is not triggering at all.

`NSURLSession` - How to support **http** `authentication challenge`?
Also it will useful if its workable to **`Kingfisher`** 3rd party framework too.

Comment: Maybe you need to provide the auth param in request header instead?

Comment: @Tj3n could you please elaborate

Comment: Have you test your api with postman? It have authorization tab which contains several auth type, maybe u can provide the auth beforehand, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105322/ios-cocoa-nsurlsession-handling-basic-https-authorization)